# Run preloader bar in reverse in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the following ActionScript for my Flash preloader, what this does is have the preloader bar fill from the top to the bottom.

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void{
    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    preloader_mc.bar_mc.scaleY = loaded/total;
    preloader_mc.loader_txt.text = Math.floor((loaded/total)*100)+ "%";

    if (total == loaded){
        play();
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
    }
}
```

How would I alter this so that instead, it starts off full and then decreases in size down to zero (downwards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse the `scaleY` value.
`loaded/total` will going from **0 to 1**, so doing `1 - loaded/total` it will going from **1 to 0**, and the your preloader will shrink instead of growing :

```
preloader_mc.bar_mc.scaleY = 1 - loaded/total;
```